# Rails Tutorial: Reason for CGI.escapeHTML in Chapter 12 Exercise 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For the [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users), I know what the solution is. (It's also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975747/michael-hartl-ror-tutorial-chapter-12-exercise-2).) I do not understand why escaping the HTML is necessary though. I guess I'm confused on what it does. Specifically, in the user_profile_test.rb file given by this tutorial, we have the following test:

```
test "profile display" do
  get user_path(@user)
  ...
  assert_select 'div.pagination'
  @user.microposts.paginate(page: 1).each do |micropost|
    assert_match micropost.content, response.body
  end
end
```

Why is escaping the HTML not necessary in this test and is necessary in the chapter 12 exercise one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape HTML, to sanitize your data before it hits your database.

From the Ruby Docs:
    `CGI::escapeHTML('Usage: foo "bar" <baz>')`
    `# => "Usage: foo &quot;bar&quot; &lt;baz&gt;"`

If you didn't use `escapeHTML` someone could put a `<script>` tag in there and potentially write some harmful code. Maybe it's a social network site and people are embedding some malware in their comment and then everyone that visits for page has a bad time as well as you.

As far as the test goes, I think that's the reason, because you can control the test. But at the same time I really don't see why wouldn't add `escapeHTML` to the test as well, but maybe it's just not required where you are studying.